# React Native Flatlist - render items partly on top of another

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

In my project I've built a diagram using flatlist. Each item is a bar in the diagram and when pressing a bar a popup appears displaying the bar data in text. I found this popup only overlaps one of the adjacent bars, where I obviously want it to overlap the bars on both sides.

I've built a minimal reproducible example in the snack below. Any chance of getting the red bars to overlap both the previous and next item in the flatlist? I've played around with different style attributes - zIndex, overflow, etc. No luck.

Check this snack please https://snack.expo.dev/@kred67/react-native-flatlist-issue.

[image]

The red bars are absolutely positioned Views inside each flatlist item. As you can see it only overlaps the previous item in the list and not the subsequent one.

UPDATE: This is how I want the red bars to appear:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28751
I think this link maybe help you

Comment: It helps much indeed. Seems this issue been around for a while. There is an iOS fix involving using the CellRendererComponent prop for the flatlist, but it seems an overkill for my use case. I can work around this by increasing the distance between the bars in my diagram.